# Flutter Provider explanation : Exception has occurred. ProviderNotFoundException

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, state-management

I'm new to flutter. I've got the below code and it's not running. I know how to fix the error (one solution). But I wanted to understand the concept here of why it's not running. Also, all the other different solutions to fix this issue.

I would like to know much detailed explanation about the below code why the error occurred?

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<String>(
      create: (context) => "Passing Data",
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: Provider.of<String>(context),
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read up on [BuildContext](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html), [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) and [InheritedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html), but I also can offer a condensed explanation:

You cannot use the **Provider** within the same widget in which you're returning it. It must be inherited (i.e. the Provider must come down from a parent or ancestor widget) or have a separate context. You must either create a separate widget above (i.e. a parent widget) that then includes the **MaterialApp** if you still want to use it there. This is mostly because of the **Context** reference. The context is used to pull data from the widget's ancestors (in this case, a provided value from above), and **Provider** is nothing more than a wrapper around **InheritedWidget**, therefore in order to fetch the provided value, the context must be inherited or be its own context.

In your case, the Provider must be either located on a parent widget so you can inherit the value being handed down to you, or you must use something like a **Consumer** widget or a **Builder** widget which supply their own context, but never use the same context both for injecting and fetching the provider.

You either can do it like this, where the **Builder** widget supplies its own **context**:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<String>(
      create: (context) => "Passing Data",
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) {
          return MaterialApp(
            title: Provider.of<String>(context),
            home: HomePage()
          );
        } 
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

or like this, where you see in the **runApp** how we wrap the Provider around the **MyApp**, creating a hierarchy, allowing for the context to be inherited by the **MyApp** widget, from which you can safely fetch the provided value.

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(
    Provider<String>(
      create: (context) => "Passing Data",
      child: MyApp()
    )
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: Provider.of<String>(context),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```